# Bridge wifi and ethernet

Tags: networking

I want to bridge wlan0 and eth0 to get Internet from wlan0 to eth0 to plug in a switch.
I configured wpa-supplicant and have this interfaces file:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
      address 192.168.1.5   #ip in wlan0 for Internet
      netmask 255.255.255.0   #netmask in wlan0 for Internet
      gateway 192.168.1.1   #gateway in wlan0 for Internet
      bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
      bridge_stp off
      bridge_maxwait 5

wpa-iface wlan0
wpa-bridge br0
wpa-driver wext
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

It seems not to work. What could be the problem?

### Edit

Now I know: bridging from wifi to ethernet doesn't work, if the WiFi adapter isn't in host mode because it isn't allowed to send any information with an different MAC address! I thought that's only the problem with bridging from Ethernet to WiFi.

Comment: Did you already create the br0 interface using the command `brctl addbr br0`?  What does `ip show addr` display?

Comment: plz paste you ifconfig!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a sharp shoot:

To share wlan0 and eth0

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
     wpa-driver wext
     wpa-ssid YOUR_SSID
     wpa-ap-scan 1
     wpa-proto RSN
     wpa-pairwise CCMP
     wpa-group CCMP
     wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
     wpa-psk "passphrase"

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.3.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.3.255

## remove rules and chains first
up /sbin/iptables -F
 up /sbin/iptables -X
  up /sbin/iptables -t nat -F

    ## mask eth0, activate port forwarding and nat
up /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -o wlan0 -i eth0 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
 up /sbin/iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
  up /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE 
   up /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 

## use dnsmasq-base
## on range 192.168.3.10 - 192.168.3.20
up /usr/bin/killall dnsmasq
 up /bin/sleep 2
  post-up /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -i eth0 -I wlan0 -F 192.168.3.10,192.168.3.20,infinite

## if you use dnsmasq activate this
## if dnsmasq-base deactive this
## dnsmasq restart
# post-up /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

for dnsmasq

/etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
# dhcp active for eth0
interface=eth0

# no dhcp for wlan0
no-dhcp-interface=wlan0

# range / Lease-Time
dhcp-range=interface:eth0,192.168.3.10,192.168.3.20,infinite
```

Comment: I have had problems because I haven't installed dnsmasq. Now it works!

Comment: Interesting.  This is what I was looking for..  Upvote.